# How can I modify the CSS only for the search results page of Wordpress?

Tags: themes, css, search

I use the wordpress theme Sensible WP. When I do a search this is what appears as the URL:

https://www.example.com/?s=my+search+text

I need to modify the CSS for this page only, not all pages, but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: please ask in the theme's support forum at https://wordpress.org/support/theme/sensible-wp

Comment: The support forum is not active.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this and found the solution:

Just add

> .search-results

to your class. ie:

```
.search-results .title {
color: red;
}
```

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( is_search() ) {
    echo ‘<style>.class{color:red;}</style>’;
}
```